# NameValueCollection in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, namevaluecollection

I want to use NameValueCollection in windows phone 8, but I can not see this option in WP8 SDK. Can you help me please?

Comment: It seems it has stupidly been removed from the System.Collections.Specialized namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function has been removed.

But a query can be manipulated using parsing and a SortedDictionary. i.e. This snippet sorts a query string:

```
public string sortQuery(string myUrl)
    {
        string url = myUrl.Substring(0, myUrl.IndexOf("?") + 1);
        string q = myUrl.Substring(myUrl.IndexOf("?") + 1);
        string[] pr = q.Split('&');
        SortedDictionary<string,string> d = new SortedDictionary<string,string>();

        foreach (string s in pr)
        {
            string[] prm = s.Split('=');
            string key = prm[0];
            string value = "";
            if (prm.Length > 1) { value = "=" + prm[1]; }
            d.Add(key, value);
        }

        string result = "";

        foreach (var k in d.Keys)
        {
            result += k + d[k] + "&";
        }

        result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
        return url + result;
    }
```

Comment: It'll throw an exception in a querystring like ´?q=1&q=2´. Dictionaries dont support same keys.

Comment: Nor atomic explosions. I can see dozen of potential crashes but fortunately this is a snippet, not a commercial product.

Comment: It's pretty common same parameters in querystrings, I think thats why NameValueCollection was used to parse it in .NET. But dont know why Microsoft remove in Windows Phone.

Comment: Thanks, good to know! And yeah, personnaly i don't understand the whole point of breaking a framework into a lite framework. Probably a huge error from MS.